# I need help fixing the Bug in my list array

Tags: javascript, react-native, arraylist, react-hooks

I code community I have a bug in my search bar. The app is very easy... Ever time a user creates a name it displays in a list array. My problem is that when the user creates a name that name is not displaying my the list but when I search the name, it does show the list.

Here the video so you can have a better understanding 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIM-H4xXqMw

and the code. I need help in my search bar and display the list when clicking the button

```
FolderHome.js - component

const [folder, emptyFolder] = useState([]);
const data = folder;

const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
let [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data);

//this function is when the user press the button we want to use the folderName(value) and display in a list.
//then when we add a foldername we update and add a new folder name.
//To understand I am just adding a folder name into my empty array. Now my array as a Folder inside.

const addFolder = (folderName) => {
    emptyFolder((currentFolder) => [
      ...currentFolder,
      { id: Math.random().toString(), value: folderName },
    ]);
  };

//Search
  const _searchFilterFunction = (event, data) => {
    let newData = [];
    setSearchTerm({ searchTerm: event });
    if (event) {
      newData = data.filter((item) => {
        const textData = event.toUpperCase();
        const nameFolder = item.value.toUpperCase();
        return nameFolder.includes(textData);
      });
      setFilteredData([...newData]);
    } else {
      setFilteredData([...data]);
    }
  };

return (
    <View style={styles.HomeContainer}>
      <TextInput
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
        style={styles.search}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={(value) => {
          _searchFilterFunction(value, data);
        }}
      />
      <FolderInput myFolder={addFolder} />

      {filteredData.map((item, index) => {
        return <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

FolderInput.js - Component

```
const FolderInput = (props) => {
  //This function we handle the input and output off Folder
  const [outputFolder, inputFolder] = useState("");

  //This arrow function is handling the folder name on onChangeText in TextInput
  const folderName = (entereName) => {
    inputFolder(entereName);
  };

  //Function to clear input when done enter folder name
  const clearInput = () => {
    props.myFolder(outputFolder);
    inputFolder("");
  };

  return (
    // TouchableWithoutFeedback allow to register a touche withou nothing happen to it
    <View style={styles.outputContainer}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          Keyboard.dismiss();
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.containerFolder}>
          <TextInput
            blurOnSubmit
            placeholder="Create Folder"
            style={styles.containerTextInput}
            onChangeText={folderName}
            //we pass the name folder into is value by biding and store into outputFolder
            value={outputFolder}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <AntDesign
              onPress={clearInput}
              name="addfolder"
              backgroundColor="black"
              size={30}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FolderInput;
```

Thank you so much for all hard work your in advance
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have filteredData as state. it is a computed result of searchTerm and folder.
just declare it as:

```js
const filteredDate = folder.filter((item) => {
        const textData = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
        const nameFolder = item.value.toUpperCase();
        return nameFolder.includes(textData);
      });
```

You can take a look at a simple implementation of search in this snack:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-cori-n704s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am not really following. How about my if-else statement? where should I declare filteredDate?

Comment: in the body of the component.
you don't need the if else statement because you are just creating the filtered list based on the data and searchTerm. every render the filteredData will be re-evaluated.
(if you want you can memoize it with useMemo and then in will only be re-evaluated then folder or searchTerm changes)

Comment: sorry bother you so much I am still learning all this. So far I am able to display my list but when I am going to search I found an error saying: TypeError: searchTerm.toUpperCase(); it is not a function. searchTerm.toUpperCase(); is undefined

Comment: Here's the code so far: 

// My state 
 const [folder, emptyFolder] = useState([]);
 const data = folder;
 const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

//Search function
 const _searchFilterFunction = (event) => {
   setSearchTerm({ searchTerm: event });
 };

 const filteredDate = folder.filter((item) => {
   const textData = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
   const nameFolder = item.value.toUpperCase();
   return nameFolder.includes(textData);
 });

// Return statement
{filteredDate.map((item) => {
       return <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>;
     })}

Comment: you are probably not changing the search term correctly . your onChange function should be e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)

Comment: I did make some changes but still getting the same error.  here's my code...   const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const filteredData = folder.filter((item) => {
    const textData = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
    const nameFolder = item.value.toUpperCase();
    return nameFolder.includes(textData);
  });        onChange={handleChange} {filteredData.map((item) => {
        return <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>;
      })}.   sorry bother you really need help on this :)

Comment: you can take a look at this example of how i would use search https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-cori-n704s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: happy to help :) I will add this snack to the answer and would be happy if you accept it